# how to print array's even numbers sum/avarage and odd numbers sum/average?

Tags: swift

```
var a = [32,37,68,66,97,38,16,86,35,58]
```

I want to know,
how to print even num's sum&average , odd num's sum&average

Comment: If you show us what you've already tried, we can help you fix it or point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### O(*n*)

You can do it in one sweep :

```
let (oddsSum, oddsCount, evensSum, evensCount) = a.reduce(into:(0, 0, 0, 0)) { tuple, element in
    if element % 2 != 0 {
        tuple.0 += element
        tuple.1 += 1
    } else {
        tuple.2 += element
        tuple.3 += 1
    }
}

let oddsAverage = oddsCount == 0 ? 0.0 : Double(oddsSum) / Double(oddsCount)
let evensAverage = evensCount == 0 ? 0.0 : Double(evensSum) / Double(evensCount)
```

Which would yield the following results :

> ```
> oddsSum       //169 
> oddsAverage   //56.33333333333334 
> evensSum      //364 
> evensAverage  //52
> ```

---

### Two arrays

You can create two arrays of odds and evens like so :

```
let a = [32, 37, 68, 66, 97, 38, 16, 86, 35, 58]

let (odds, evens) = a.reduce(into:([Int](), [Int]())) { tuple, element in
    if element % 2 != 0 {
        tuple.0.append(element)
    } else {
        tuple.1.append(element)
    }
}
```

`odds` and `evens` are two arrays of integers: `[Int]`.

---

### Sums

To calculate the sums :

```
let oddsSum = odds.reduce(0, +)           //169
let evensSum = odds.reduce(0, +)          //364
```

You can also use [`cblas_dasum(_:_:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/1513208-cblas_dasum) from the Accelerate framework, which is faster than `reduce` :

```
import Accelerate

var (odds, evens) = a.reduce(into:([Double](), [Double]())) { tuple, element in
    if element % 2 != 0 {
        tuple.0.append(Double(element))
    } else {
        tuple.1.append(Double(element))
    }
}

var oddSum = Int(cblas_dasum(Int32(odds.count), &odds, 1))
print(oddSum)     //169

var evenSum = Int(cblas_dasum(Int32(evens.count), &evens, 1))
print(evenSum)    //364
```

---

### Averages

The averages are the sums divided by the number of elements in each array.

```
let oddsAverage = odds.isEmpty ? 0.0 : Double(oddsSum) / Double(odds.count)    //56.33333333333334
let evensAverage = evens.isEmpty ? 0.0 : Double(evensSum) / Double(evens.count) //52
```

Or you can use [`vDSP_meanvD(_:_:_:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/1449784-vdsp_meanvd) from the Accelerate framework, which is faster than calculating the sum and then dividing by the count :

```
import Accelerate

var (odds, evens) = a.reduce(into:([Double](), [Double]())) { tuple, element in
    if element % 2 != 0 {
        tuple.0.append(Double(element))
    } else {
        tuple.1.append(Double(element))
    }
}

var oddAvg = 0.0
vDSP_meanvD(&odds, 1, &oddAvg, vDSP_Length(odds.count))
print(oddAvg)     //56.333333333333336

var evenAvg = 0.0
vDSP_meanvD(&evens, 1, &evenAvg, vDSP_Length(evens.count))
print(evenAvg)    //52.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an extension like this

```
extension Sequence where Self.Element == Int {
    var sum: Int {
        return self.reduce(0, { $0 + $1 })
    }
}
```

then do this:

```
var a = [38,97,25,66,90,31,16,86,33,59]
var evens = a.filter({ ($0 % 2) == 0 })
var odds = a.filter({ ($0 % 2) != 0 })

print(evens.sum)
print(odds.sum)
```

Comment: After posting this, I realized that I'm probably doing someone else's homework.

Comment: I like verbosity :)

Comment: This doesn’t give the average.

Comment: Ahh, so sorry.  have to divide by the count :)

Comment: Anyway, its like 90% there and I'm pretty sure this is someone else homework so if you can't take it from there and figure out how to get the average, then you deserve to fail.

Answer (score 0):

Without an extension so perhaps easier for beginners to understand, here is how I would do this:

```
let oddElements = a.filter{$0 % 2 == 0}
let evenElements = a.filter{$0 % 2 != 0}

let oddElementsSum = oddElements.reduce(0, {$0 + $1})
let oddElementsAverage = oddElementsSum / oddElements.count

let evenElementsSum = evenElements.reduce(0, {$0 + $1})
let evenElementsAverage = evenElementsSum / evenElements.count
```

It is possible to make the reduce statements a little shorter with

```
let oddElementsSum = oddElements.reduce(0, {+})
let evenElementsSum = evenElements.reduce(0, {+})
```

Then you can print through

```
print (oddElementsSum)
print (oddElementsAverage)
print (evenElementsSum)
print (evenElementsAverage)
```